# Uploading Image via HttpURLClient to Webserver doesn't work

Tags: java, php, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to upload an image from a devices storage to a local webserver, using the following code:

```
public class ImageUpload {

    static String LINE_END = "\r\n";
    static String TWO_HYPHENS = "--";
    static String BOUNDARY = "*****";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner mScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Path of the Image:");
        String sPath = mScanner.nextLine();

        HttpURLConnection mConnection;
        //DataInputStream mInput;
        DataOutputStream mOutput;
        int iBytesRead, iBytesAvailable, iBufferSize;
        byte[] mByteBuffer;
        int iMaxBufferSize = 1024*1024;

        String sUploadURL = "http://172.16.0.15/hsay/upload/";

        try {
            FileInputStream mInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(sPath));
            URL mUrl = new URL(sUploadURL);

            mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            mConnection.setDoInput(true);
            mConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            mConnection.setUseCaches(true);

            mConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            mConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            mConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY);

            mOutput = new DataOutputStream(mConnection.getOutputStream());
            mOutput.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + LINE_END);
            mOutput.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data); name=\"image\";filename=\"" + new File(sPath).getName() + "\"" + LINE_END);
            mOutput.writeBytes(LINE_END);

            iBytesAvailable = mInputStream.available();
            iBufferSize = Math.min(iBytesAvailable, iMaxBufferSize);
            mByteBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];
            iBytesRead = mInputStream.read(mByteBuffer, 0, iBufferSize);

            while (iBytesRead > 0) {
                mOutput.write(mByteBuffer, 0, iBufferSize);
                iBytesAvailable = mInputStream.available();
                iBufferSize = Math.min(iBytesAvailable, iMaxBufferSize);
                iBytesRead = mInputStream.read(mByteBuffer, 0, iBufferSize);
            }

            mOutput.writeBytes(LINE_END);
            mOutput.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + TWO_HYPHENS + LINE_END);

            BufferedReader mInputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String sInputLine;
            while ((sInputLine = mInputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                mStringBuilder.append(sInputLine);
            }

            System.out.println(mStringBuilder.toString());

            mInputStream.close();
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        mScanner.close();
    }
}
```

And my PHP Code:

```
$mUploadedFile = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$mUploadedFileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$mTempFile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$mError = $_FILES['image']['error'];


if ($mError > 0) {
    die("[ERROR]: File couldn't be uploaded.".$mError);
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($mTempFile, "images/".$mUploadedFile);
    echo "[SUCCESS UPLOAD]: ".$mUploadedFileType;
}
?>
```

The Output of the page is "[SUCCESS UPLOAD]", but the file isn't uploaded or I just can't find it!

The method `var_dump($_FILES)` returns the following:

> array(1) {  ["image"]=>  array(5) {    ["name"]=>    string(8) "Logo.png"    ["type"]=>    string(0) ""    ["tmp_name"]=>    string(14) "/tmp/phpyxwnos"    ["error"]=>    int(0)    ["size"]=>    int(567086)  }}

The input path was C:\Users\Daniel\Logo.png.

I did this test in Eclipse on my notebook, it should be implemented in an Android App lateron. The local webserver is a Raspberry Pi 3 with Apache2.0 running on it!

Does anyone know what's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the image not upload either? Can you do var_dump($_FILES); at the top to see what you're getting from the Java app?

Comment: In PHP you are asking for $_FILES["image"], but on the request you named it `uploadedfile`. You need the same name on both parts

Comment: @ishegg Thanks, but it still doesn't work. The file is uploaded (see var_dump output)!

Comment: I see. The reason you're getting only "[SUCCESS UPLOAD]: " is because the `type` is empty, as you can see in the dump. There can be multiple reasons for this (like MIME type config on the server). Bottom line is, you shouldn't rely on that field, since it's easily spoofed. To check the actual file type of the file, you need to check its contents.

Comment: Yes, but I still can't find the Image on the server!

Comment: Ohhh I read it all wrong. What's the result of `move_uploaded_file()`? It's a boolean, so check if it's true. Maybe you have an error on the copying of the file. Put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`at the top of the file to see any errors as well.

Comment: That's it: Warning:  move_uploaded_file(images/Logo.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/hsay/upload/index.php on line 41. Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpZAmkGt' to 'images/Logo.png' in /var/www/html/hsay/upload/index.php on line 41

Comment: Great! Now we know what's up. You need to make the folder `images/`writable, so give it 0777 permissions for example (just for testing, afterwards give it more secure, appropriate permissions).

Comment: Yeah, that was the error! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's no problem :)